# Internal Bootstrap for performance?

Tags: html, css, performance, bootstrap-4

The Fastest Website is an empty webpage, after that each bit of data added compromises performance, But this load is on the server to send all code to client,
Now, If I use bootstrap or any css library in general, from a CDN, all the processing happens in client after fetching the stylesheet, this causes a lot of delay,
So, If I include complete bootstrap stylesheet (pretty huge), and put it in a `<style>` tag on my Single Page App, all the load would be on the server, but that would be negligible compared to load on client as it is just plain text,

**So, Is it just efficient enough to include all CSS code in my page itself?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDN is always faster than your css file which will come from your server and moreover CDN also keep cache on client side from different website as well which will give your website an advantage of getting load faster.

My recommendation would be to use CDN rather than your own css for bootstrap